# How is the memory management works for non-instantiated classes in Java?

Tags: java, class, instantiation

Here is a simple snippet of code in Java:

```
class Box {
    int width;
    int height;
    int depth;
}

Box catBox = new Box();
```

When constructor `Box()` is executed, we're getting an instance of the Box class. The question is - how do the compiler behave itself when it meets this class in the code before instantiating? I mean, this part:

```
class Box {
    int width;
    int height;
    int depth;
}
```

How is this class represented in memory as an object? And is compiler creating any meta-information about this class in the memory on the step of defining such a class?

Comment: The [JVM spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/) might interest you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java classes (metadata)  will be stored inside perm-gen memory space (In Java8, this is Metaspace), which contains the names of the classes, methods, etc..

Java class metadata structure is generally represented as `klass` for which you can look [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/presenting_the_permanent_generation) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Box {
    int width;
    int height;
    int depth;
}

Box catBox = new Box();
```

As your code shows, you can create an object of class even if it doesn't have any constructor definition, because Java provides Default Constructor. You will find more clear answer in following Quastion

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/257938/why-is-there-no-default-constructor-generated-if-you-define-an-explicit-construc

Answer (score 0):

Yes Java classes are also stored as objects inside the perm-gen space allocated to JVM. Each class will have a reference as well which will take care of the methods. 
If you have observed many suggest using independent static methods which could actually load only once in this perm-gen space and reduce the memory usage as well.
If we have the same method under a class instead of static (though that can be made static) we will end up have two references in the memory for the same functionality as they are particular to a java class.